# "could not open macro storage" in custom MS-Word template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use a custom MS-Word template with a number of macros in it. Recently, the macros in my template (but not the default/Normal template or other templates) stopped working.  I am unable to look at them in the VBA editor, although Word does seem to remember they exist to the extent that I can see the names of my macros when I open the "view macros" window (though not in the organizer).  This is the case for both old and new files created with my template.  Is there any way of recovering the macros I wrote?

I have tried playing with the security settings in Word but this doesn't seem to be the source of the problem.